# Besides button, submit and <a></a>, is there other way that can make text clickable?

Tags: html, click

Besides `<input type="button" value="Click me" />, <input type="submit" value="Click me" />, <a>Click me</a>`, is there another way that can make "Click me" clickable?

Comment: I presume you mean without client script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Javascript and CSS, you can make almost everything click-able.

```
<img src="photo-thumbnail.jpg" onclick="popup_image('photo.jpg');" style="cursor:pointer;" alt="" />
```

Setting `cursor:pointer` will make an element look clickable.

But again, that will only work if Javascript is enabled.

Comment: If it works, put a tick by the side so that others know which is the answer.

Comment: I have put a tick. Is it okay?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript:

```
<span onclick="...">Eat me</a>
```

This of course only provides the reaction to the click, if you want to make it look clickable also you have to add some styling.

Answer (score 1):

By clickable do you mean something other than that it causes JavaScript onClick events to fire? Any DOM component should do that. If you want to change the cursor to indicate that something will happen when text is clicked, you can do that with [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_cursor.asp).

Comment: I mean the mouse cursor will change when you hover it over the text.